# Transformation of Vertical Strip in Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, transformation, complex-geometry

Find the image of the finite vertical strip $R: x=5 \to x=9, -\pi \leq y\leq \pi$ of z-plane under exponential function.

The things I tried:

$w = e^z = e^{(x+iy)} = e^x(cos y) + i e^x(sin y)$

$\implies w  = u + iv$

$\implies  u = e^x(cos y ), v = e^x(sin y)$

$(5,\pi) \implies (-e^5, 0)$

$(9,\pi) \implies (-e^9,0)$

How to proceed from here and find image?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $z=x+i t$ with $-\pi \leq t\leq  \pi $ and $5\leq x\leq 9$, then $\left|e^z\right|=e^x$. That's a circle in the image plane

Answer (score -1):

$w = e^z = e^{(x+iy)} = e^x e^{iy} = e^x(cos y + i sin y)$

i.e., image of $(x_0,y_0)$ is $e^{x_0}(cos y_0 + i sin y_0) $

Now for any vertical strip, $x_0$ is fixed and $y_0$ varies from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ i.e., it describes a semi-circle in the right half plane with a radius of $e^{x_0}$.

Since $x_0$ varies from 5 to 9, the radii of these semi-circles vary from $e^5$ to $e^9$. Thus the transformation is a semi-annulus in right half plane as shown below.

[image]